# How can I ascertain what the git process is currently doing?

Tags: git

About 15 minutes ago, I did a simple merge of a simple branch `bug-fix` into another branch `develop`, locally on my machine. Soon after, the `git` process on my machine began using CPU heavily and is still going.

I'd like to understand *what* it's doing.

If this information helps: about 1 month ago I lost data from my repo, and I believe it was because I force quit `git` while it was doing an auto-stash of a large set of 10,000+ files. (When you click to checkout another branch but have a dirty working directory, "auto-stash" is what my version of Github Desktop does for you, without asking.) I recovered that large set of files and moved it out of version control completely, but there's still record of it in my repo, probably in dangling blobs? Here is the output of `ls -lh .git/objects/pack`.

```
-r--r--r--  1 myUserName  staff   1.1K Jan 13 16:46 pack-1f895bdbf5c5e6a3ddeb3cef06c0719d0faae49a.idx
-r--r--r--  1 myUserName  staff   2.5G Jan 13 16:46 pack-1f895bdbf5c5e6a3ddeb3cef06c0719d0faae49a.pack
```

So what's `git` doing with my CPU and how long could this take? Is it doing `gc`? I believe it's been only about 30 days since those dangling items were last accessed.

UPDATE: an hour or two later, here I am. `git` is finished. Here's the new output of `ls -lh .git/objects/pack`:

```
-r--r--r--  1 myUserName  staff   1.1K Jan 13 16:46 pack-1f895bdbf5c5e6a3ddeb3cef06c0719d0faae49a.idx
-r--r--r--  1 myUserName  staff   2.5G Jan 13 16:46 pack-1f895bdbf5c5e6a3ddeb3cef06c0719d0faae49a.pack
-r--r--r--  1 myUserName  staff   1.2M Feb 14 19:38 pack-5e95cdd67c24eb3566c5c2d1d5e6819debfe48d0.idx
-r--r--r--  1 myUserName  staff    13G Feb 14 19:38 pack-5e95cdd67c24eb3566c5c2d1d5e6819debfe48d0.pack
```

Now I'm probably moving on to the task of finding and removing the appropriate files / blobs from git altogether.

Comment: It's probably running `git repack` to build new pack files. Use whatever process-display program you like (on Linux, `top` is very nice for this) to see what's running.

Comment: Thanks for the `git repack` suggestion. I was hoping to be able to get more detail than what my process-display program tells me (e.g. `top` just tells me that `git` is running). It's using quite a bit of memory too... hopefully it's just normal behavior!

Comment: Use `c` to toggle command line (and then you may need to scroll to see arguments). Or use `ps`, the non-update-y version of `top` :-)